# Difference between DBIx::Class and DBIx::Abstract?

Tags: perl, dbi

I am very new to perl and I was going through Perl ORM , I encountered DBIx::Class and DBIx::Abstract, from what I inferred they both seem to be ORMs . Is there any difference I am missing?
Thanks

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Abstract#DEPRICATED   DBIx::Class isn't deprecated. That's a pretty significant difference :)

Answer (score 1):

DBIx::Abstract is a low-level tool for manipulating databases (it's quite like [SQL::Abstract](https://metacpan.org/pod/SQL::Abstract), which DBIx::Class uses). It is not an ORM at all.

It has also been deprecated (sorry, "[depricated](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Abstract#DEPRICATED)"!). So I can't recommend using it.